# What is preventing my function from being invoked?

Tags: javascript, object, canvas

I'm trying to draw a random set of lines on a Canvas, with positions `0 - 100` corresponding to the `X` values and randomly assigned sizes the `Y` values. However, for some reason, my `drawLines()` function doesn't appear to be being invoked. Nothing appears in the console and nothing is drawn. What did I do wrong?

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// we could accomplish this using Classes instead

// create object that holds all lines position and sizes
class Lines {
    constructor(numLines = 100) {
        this.numLines = numLines;
        this.positions = function () {
        var array = []
        for (let i = 1; i <= this.numLines; i++) {
            array.push(i)
        }
        return array
        };
         this.sizes = function () {
        var array2 = []
        for (let i = 1; i <= this.numLines; i++) {
            array2.push(math.random() * numLines)
        }
        return array2
        };
    }

    // create function that draws all lines based on how the object looks 
    drawLines() {
        for (let i = 1; i <= Lines.positions; i++) {
            ctx.moveTo(this.positions[i], 0);
            ctx.lineTo(this.positions[i], this.sizes[i]*5);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
}



var newLines = new Lines(100);
newLines.drawLines()

function drawLine (position, size) {


    ctx.moveTo(position, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(position, size*5);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Lines.positions should be `this.positions().length`

Comment: To improve your understanding of classes and objects, I’d recommend you to use your console more. Use `console.log(Lines)`. You won’t see a `positions` property there, so there’s no reason to use `Lines.positions`. You’re assigning something to `this.positions`, so try `console.log(this)`; that’s where the `positions` property is, so there’s a reason to use `this.positions`.

Answer (score 0):

The `positions` and `sizes` members are functions and they aren't being called. So your `drawLines` function could be something like this:

```js
drawLines() {
    var positions = this.positions()
    var sizes = this.sizes()
    for (let i = 1; i <= positions.length; i++) {
        ctx.moveTo(positions[i], 0);
        ctx.lineTo(positions[i], sizes[i]*5);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

Also `math.random()` should be `Math.random()`,

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is that `positions` and `sizes` are functions, yet you're attempting to use them like properties. You need to invoke the functions to generate the arrays. I would also suggest you store the result, not repeatedly call those functions as you will get a different result every time you call `sizes()`.

In addition, `math` needs to be `Math`, you can use `fill()` and `map()` to generate the content in the arrays, and your for loop should go from `0` to `99`, not `1` to `99`.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// create object that holds all lines position and sizes
class Lines {
  constructor(numLines = 100) {
    this.numLines = numLines;
    this.positions = () => Array(this.numLines).fill().map((_, i) => i + 1),
    this.sizes = () => Array(this.numLines).fill().map(_ => Math.random() * numLines)
  }

  // create function that draws all lines based on how the object looks 
  drawLines() {
    const positions = this.positions();
    const sizes = this.sizes();
    for (let i = 0; i <= positions.length; i++) { 
      ctx.moveTo(positions[i], 0);
      ctx.lineTo(positions[i], sizes[i] * 5);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
}

var newLines = new Lines(100);
newLines.drawLines();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```